# Nodemailer works in development in localhost, but not in production VPS. How do I figure out what is wrong?

Tags: node.js, express, smtp, nodemailer, rhel

I am using Nodemailer in an ExpressJS Node application on a RHEL VPS to send form submissions via email, from and to an external email server. My application runs as expected on my computer using nodemon to serve to localhost, but when I try to use pm2 to run my app on my RHEL server, it does not send the emails. The app works as expected besides the nodemailer form submission. I am able to access all the routes and I even get a status code 200 when submitting the form, but that may be due to the way I set up my Express server's POST route and callback. Port 465 is open and I opened up port 25 as well just in case, but I'm not sure if that was necessary. I am new to email servers and how they work, so I could use some help if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Here's a copy of my express server JS code:

```
require("dotenv").config();
console.log("token", process.env.PASS);

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const path = require('path')
const PORT = process.env.PORT;

// Middleware
app.use([
  express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')),
  express.urlencoded({ extended: false }),
  express.json(),
]);

// Set routes to static pages
app.get("/home", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../public/index.html")); 
});
app.get("/contact", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../public/contact.html")); 
});
app.get("/services", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../public/services.html")); 
});
app.get("/pricing", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../public/pricing.html")); 
});
app.get("/about", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../public/about.html")); 
});
app.get("/gallery", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../public/gallery.html")); 
});

// Post contact form data to SMTP server
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);

  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: process.env.HOST,
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.EMAIL,
      pass: process.env.PASS,
    },
    tls: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    },
  });

  const mailOptions = {
    from: process.env.EMAIL,
    to: process.env.RECIP,
    subject: `Message from ${req.body.name} - ${req.body.email}`,
    text: `Customer Info:

    Name: ${req.body.name}
    Phone: ${req.body.phone}
    Email: ${req.body.email}
    Jobsite: ${req.body.jobsite}
    Message: ${req.body.message}`,
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.send("error");
    } else {
      console.log("Message Sent: " + info.response);
      res.send("success");
    }
  });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

I tried doing the form submissions in the same manner as I did in development in my localhost on my computer, but it does not work. It may have something to do with RHEL's security features or something else I'm completely unaware of. I've been searching for answers on this particular issue for a few days and haven't found anything as of yet. I'm unsure of what could be causing this issue with the ports opened and with the Express application seemingly working fine besides nodemailer on the VPS.